# Convert variable from number to string only if not null, otherwise leave as null

Tags: typescript

```js
// When:
// s == null, n == null, I want result to be null
// s == null, n == 1, I want result to be "1"
// s == "2", n == null, I want result to be "2"
// s == "2", n ==  1, I want result to be "2"
const s: string | null = null;
const n: number | null = 1;

const result: string | null = 
    (s ?? (n != null) ? String(n) : null); // Is there a better way?

console.log(result);
```

Is there a simpler/better way to write the logic for `result` in Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) might be helpful to conditionally cast the `number` to a `string`.

```
const result: string | null = (s ?? n?.toString()) ?? null;
```

It is still not so pretty, but it's a little more concise.

---

Optional chaining sources:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Arguably a bit easier to read at a glance:

```
const result: string | null = s || n?.toString() || null;
```